# how much LaTeX is enough or too much

Tags: discussion, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we avoid mathjax, if it is not necessary?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733/should-we-avoid-mathjax-if-it-is-not-necessary)

Given that each separate bit of LaTeX requires a bit of extra processing; and given that these sites get viewed from a variety of different javascript-capable devices (not just powerful PCs), I've tended towards only using LaTeX where essential for meaning.

But is that the right thing to do?

I ask because of [this edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/88010/revisions), where a mod added LaTeX markup.

Rather than ignore or rollback, I figured I'd ask here.

Comment: See this question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733/should-we-avoid-mathjax-if-it-is-not-necessary

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for pointing that out. I was sure there was a duplicate somewhere, but I couldn't find it at first glance, and I wanted to respond as the mod who made the edit in question. I see that I made several similar points to Jeff's answer; but I was not even aware that MathJax makes the same loading time penalty regardless of use!

Comment: ah, thanks for the dupe spot. @ZevChonoles NB it's not about load time, it's about processing time

Comment: I guess I've just been conflating those two notions unintentionally (shows how much I know about the internet). At any rate I believe Jeff Atwood in any matter regarding the operation of the site.

Answer (score 4):

That's a good question. I suppose I am spoiled by my almost always viewing the site on a PC :) There is certainly a balancing act between

- a clean, consistent look for the site
- the need for $\LaTeX$ to express complex mathematics
- giving reasonable loading times for as many users as possible

I would say that, in the example in question, since there was almost no $\LaTeX$, adding a little bit more doesn't do too much harm, and it makes for a consistent look for the site. However, if presented with a page where there were a ***large*** number of simple mathematical expressions, all of which could be easily expressible, and more importantly *readable*, without $\LaTeX$, I absolutely agree that adding it would have a net negative effect, due to the longer loading time.

Now for example, adding $\LaTeX$ to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1919/ignoring-elements-of-small-order-in-the-simple-group-of-order-60), where the OP made an impressive use of HTML to format this mathematics (I believe the reason was that it was posted before the site got $\LaTeX$ abilities), I suppose might be considered a borderline decision. While it was certinaly readable without the $\LaTeX$, I think that the much nicer look and feel of $\LaTeX$ outweighed a shorter loading time.

I also would posit that, as the computing speed of our gadgets improve, the loading time will be less of an issue; and I think that formatting with $\LaTeX$ adds value to the site as a repository for readable questions and answers in the long term.

So, there is not really a right answer; do what you feel is best. I tend to favor using $\LaTeX$ in general, but there are certainly situations where using it might cause more harm than good.

Comment: I'm honestly not a big fan of TeXing up things at all cost. If it's a good question with good answers, okay, I understand. But bumping up [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5783/what-is-the-center-of-v-the-klein-4-group) for example, essentially to change V to $V$ seems a bit much (this question has rested well and it won't be of interest to anyone).

Comment: Sorry, I do tend to get carried away when I get started on a LaTeXing spree. I'll stick to the good stuff from now on.

Comment: Thanks, I do appreciate the efforts in general, but not particularly so in this instance :)